# If condition in hover status in styled-component always takes the "else" value

Tags: css, reactjs, if-statement, styled-components, react-props

I've been developing a project using rick and morty api and encountered a strange issue. Basically, I am not able to use "props" correctly in a condition in styled-components; it always takes the value in first "else" **even if conditions work correctly (I console.log my conditions and there were no issues; it enters correctly every single one of them)**

Let me explain it further...

Here's my isAlive prop to be used in my styled-components file:

`<StatusDot isAlive={data.status} />`

These are styles belonging to the StatusDot component:

```
export const StatusDot = styled.span`
    display: inline-block;
    height: .8rem;
    width: .8rem;
    
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transition: .8s background ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    
    
    ${CharacterCard}:hover & {
        background: ${(props) => (props.isAlive === "Alive" ? "rgb(85, 204, 68)" : "rgb(214, 61, 46)")};
        transition-delay: .8s;
    }
`;
```

Whenever I hover on CharacterCard, it always takes the RGB code in the else block even if my props.isAlive is "Alive". The same issue happens again when I write a nested if check; it always picks the RGB code in the else block.

This is the nested code I wrote:

```
background: ${props => props.isAlive === "Alive"
     ? "rgb(85, 204, 68)" : 
     props.isAlive === "Dead" ? "rgb(214, 61, 46)" : "black"};
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've tested this out and the logic works fine for me, are you sure the value of `props.isAlive` is what you expect it to be? Since you're matching strings if the value was only a character off it would always end up in the else. It would explain the behavior you're experiencing. [Simplified example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-haze-2ztvj?file=/src/App.js:0-23).

Answer (score 0):

Is your span expecting the `isAlive` prop?
If a prop is undefined is defined as `false`

```
export const StatusDot = styled.span<{isAlive: 'Alive' | 'Dead' | 'unknown' }>``
```